# Why do I get a "key already added" error when using the key from a GroupBy in ToDictionary?

Tags: c#, linq

I had thought that a Linq `GroupBy` would always produce unique keys, and yet when I project the results of a `GroupBy` into a `Dictionary` using `.ToDictionary()`, I get an error saying "an item with the same key has already been added":

[image]

Here's the code in question:

```
return DbContext.Responsibilities
    .GroupBy(r => r.RoleCode)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

[Here `Responsibilities` is a `DbSet` of entities whose `RoleCode` member is a simple `int` property.]

If I change this to produce a sequence of anonymous types, and *then* create a dictionary from that, it runs without error:

```
return DbContext.Responsibilities
    .GroupBy(r => r.RoleCode)
    .Select(g => new { Code = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
    .ToDictionary(i => i.Code, i => i.Count);
```

Why does that make such a difference?

FYI, if I create a temporary `List` variable to hold the anonymous types, here's what the values are:

[image]

So, no duplicate keys.

Comment: Can you try doing a `ToList` after the `GroupBy` call and see if there is a duplicate grouping?

Comment: @MindSwipe: I already did - see the end of the question.

Comment: I don't mean the anonymous types. I mean do this `var temp = DbContext.Responsibilities.GroupBy(r => r.RoleCode).ToList();` and inspect the `temp` variable

Comment: What would happen if you would run your own version of `ToDictionary`, copy-pasted from [original](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,a6091311eadfdd8a)?

Comment: @MindSwipe: Ah, I see. Will do.

Comment: @MindSwipe: wasn't my idea - I think you meant to respond to Dialecticus.

Comment: @Dialecticus what would change if OP were to copy paste the source, compile it himself, and run it opposed to using the precompiled binary from the Framework? [at] Gary sorry 'bout that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple Google search led me to this blog post:

http://code-ninja.org/blog/2014/07/24/entity-framework-never-call-groupby-todictionary/

The simple answer is that ToDictionary doesn't translate into an Entity Framework query, but it enumerates the result from Group By.

Comment: That "simple answer" part doesn't really explain it though - the logical results of `GroupBy` *should* be able to be fed into a simple ToDictionary call. The problem is that it's not really doing the GroupBy properly when followed by ToDictionary. We don't need ToDictionary itself to be translated, but we *do* need GroupBy to be translated appropriately.

Comment: That does explain it. Or at least, it's advice that I can follow (don't call `ToDictionary` on the results of a `GroupBy`). So thanks - that's all I really need.
I wish you'd left out the snarky "simple Google search", though. I did search for this, and didn't find anything. Maybe I used poor search terms. Sue me :-).